# winRT storage file issue

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, c#-5.0

```
    public static async Task SaveFileAsync(string FileName, T data)
    {
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.WriteObject(memStream, data);

        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(FileName,
            CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            await memStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
            await stream.FlushAsync();
        }
    }

    public static async Task<T> RestoreFileAsync(string FileName)
    {
        T result = default(T);
        try
        {
            StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(FileName);
            using (IInputStream inStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
            {
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                result = (T)serializer.ReadObject(inStream.AsStreamForRead());
                return result;
            }
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

I'm using this code to save and retrieve my data and it works fine.
sometimes i start my app, and suddenly all data removed, i really dont know why.
i tried `DataContractJsonSerializer` and saving it as .txt file, and still the same problem.
there is no exception or error.
I also checked the file it self, the .xml and .txt removes all content.
I'm very confused actually.

Comment: Did you see this behavior in unittests ? In my scenarios they always get a new local folder. Does ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder change when the content is removed ? 
Do you have the problem when writing simple text?

Comment: yes local folder change when the content is removed, i don't have any other problem, there is no error no exception, sometimes not always it just removes it.

Comment: after digging around, if i change anything in the appxmanifest every thing will be re-installed, but also that's not the issue.
i keep testing the app, is it because I'm running the app from visual studio from time to time ?

Comment: I think so. I have this behavior in my unit tests, not in the running application.

Do you start with the emulator , localpc or remote pc ? And does this make any change?

Comment: i keep testing my app with everything, and it's the save behavior.

Comment: What when you start the app with the link from the Moden Start screen ? (Without vs ?)

Answer (score 2):

Issues like this are usually a locking issue. You have the stream open when the app closes and the resulting file is empty. This is expected. Sometimes you use async operations in multiple unit tests which create a race condition. This is expected. You can solve this by locking the thread.

Read this article and see if it helps you: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/02/walkthrough-locking-asynchronous-file.html I really hope it does.